# Java - How to convert Scala Stream to Java Stream?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have a Java application that receives a `Scala Stream`.

I need to convert this to a `Java Stream`.

How can I do this *in Java*?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Which exactly type you have on Scala side, and which type you need on Java side?

Comment: Scala side is creating a Scala Stream, and on the Java side I need to convert this to a Java input/output stream,

Answer (score 6):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the standard library includes [`scala.jdk.javaapi.StreamConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/javaapi/StreamConverters$.html) which provides Java to Scala implicit stream conversions:

```
import scala.jdk.javaapi.StreamConverters;

// val scalaStream = Stream(1, 2, 3)
StreamConverters.asJavaSeqStream(scalaStream);
// java.util.stream.Stream[Int] = java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@3cccf515
```

Note that `Stream`s are renamed `LazyList` in Scala 2.13, in which case:

```
// val scalaLazyList = LazyList(1, 2, 3)
StreamConverters.asJavaSeqStream(scalaLazyList);
// java.util.stream.Stream[Int] = java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@4997c13
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit of a long way around, but you can convert the scala stream to an iterable, to a java iterable, then construct the java stream from the java iterable:

```
scala>
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def stream2javaStream[T](scalaStream: scala.Stream[T]): java.util.stream.Stream[T] = {
    StreamSupport.stream(scalaStream.toIterable.asJava.spliterator(), false);
}


stream2javaStream((1 to 100).toStream)

res0: java.util.stream.Stream[Int] = java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@2489e84a
```

While roundabout, this does not "realize" the stream, maintaining its efficiency.

```
scala>
stream2javaStream((1 to 100).toStream.map{i => println(i); i})
1
res1: java.util.stream.Stream[Int] = java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@9b21bd3
```

only prints 1 for the head of the stream

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to process the stream in parallel you can simply subclass AbstractSpliterator:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport
import java.util.{Spliterator, Spliterators}

def streamToJava[T](s: Stream[T]): java.util.stream.Stream[T] = {
    var ss: Stream[T] = s
    val splitr = new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator[T](Long.MaxValue, Spliterator.IMMUTABLE) {
      override def tryAdvance(action: Consumer[_ >: T]): Boolean = ss match {
        case Stream.Empty => false
        case h #:: tl => {ss = tl; action.accept(h); true}
      }
    }
    StreamSupport.stream(splitr, false)
  }
```

The other answer (I'm too new to comment) is incorrect as it calls size which materialises the entire stream.